# OAuth in simple php without class

Tags: php, oauth

i want to generate the signature this code gives me using simple php with no oauth class:

```
$oauth = new OAuth($my_key, $my_secret);
$bodyHash = base64_encode(sha1($body_content, true)); //contains the body
$sig = $oauth->generateSignature('GET', $url, Array("oauth_body_hash" => $bodyHash));
```

what i have done so far is this:

```
    $bodyHash = base64_encode(sha1($xml, true));
    $result_data = array(
        'oauth_body_hash' => $bodyHash
    );
    $result_data_keys = array_keys($result_data);

    sort($result_data_keys);

    $launch_params = array();
    foreach ($result_data_keys as $key) {
        array_push($launch_params, $key . "=" . rawurlencode($result_data[$key]));
    }

    $base_string = "POST&" . urlencode($sUrl) . "&" . rawurlencode(implode("&", $launch_params));

    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $base_string, $my_secret, true));
```

but im not getting the same signature!
this is the simplified version of the problem i have posted earlier here: [Building a body signed oauth xml request for LTI Outcomes service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67532425/building-a-body-signed-oauth-xml-request-for-lti-outcomes-service)
any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Are you doing this for study purposes? Otherwise there doesn't seem to be much reason to re-invent the same process again.

Comment: no, and i agree! its stupid, but where i work allowing new extension added to the server has to go through a process, which takes time i dont have, i already used the same solution to generate another signature and it worked, now i have to generate a signature with `body_hash ` to send the LTI results back to the consumer , hence why im here

Comment: Why does the OAuth class require an extension to the server?

Comment: i thought it is a server extension, mind sharing a link where i can download the class?

Comment: Are you talking about this? https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.oauth.php. But https://oauth.net/code/php/ lists a number of different Oauth libraries, and there are no doubt more if you search online. Usually I'd anticipate they don't require any special things to be installed, just the code, but the documentation will make clear.

Comment: There is a PECL OAuth extension. Op is most probably talking about that one: https://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.installation.php

Comment: yes the PECL OAuth

Comment: oauth.net doesnt let me to login so i can download the package also, i already tried that site

Comment: What do you mean? Oauth.net doesn't require you to login - at least not for that page I gave you anyway, and those libraries are all on Github, all you have to do is follow the links. Did you actually look?

Comment: my bad, i meant when i click on "oauth-api" in oauth.net, it requires me to login, i need to have oauth v1 and the rest are version 2's

Comment: The oauth-api link goes to https://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html . And yes you do need to register and log in to download it, but so what? It says you can log in with your Stackoverflow account (or several others).

Comment: and when you click on login or register button the link is broken

Comment: Well that is definitely a problem, I agree. https://github.com/socialconnect/auth says it supports Oauth v1. It claims to be supported for specific social networks but it's hard to see why it wouldn't work for another Oauth API, or perhaps you could modify it to that quicker than you can write your own client from nothing.

Comment: It also looks like there are [several other OAuth v1 PHP clients available too](https://www.google.com/search?q=Oauth+v1+client+php).